# Windows Server WDS 2008 R2 deploying windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, wds

Good Afternoon StackExchange!

I  am currently in a position where WDS is part of my duty.

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 AD/DC that also host the WDS services.

My image that I captured is Win_Pro_10_1703.1_64BIT.

When I use WDS deploy on a client machine and after selecting the image and it starts installing and gets to "Install features".  I get a error that tells me I must make sure the source is available.

If I can get help with this I would appreciate it a lot.

Thank you

Comment: Do any of those features include .Net 3.5?

Comment: Can you be more specific with the error message you receive?

Comment: In some cases I have seen this is because no proper .NET source was included within the image and/or not correctly referenced. If I had to do it, I would include the complete installed Framework(s) from the start.

Comment: Can you please post your `unattend.xml` file? Thanks!